# System.Net.Cookie --> System.Web.HttpCookie?

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know if it is possible to convert a `System.Net.Cookie` to a `System.Web.HttpCookie` ?

**What is the difference exactly?**

What I'm trying to do is simulate a pseudo-autologin feature on my site into another website.

So for example, my code does an `HttpRequest` to a remote server that returns the Authentication cookie. I then want to send that cookie to the client so they can make regular requests to the remote server as an authenticated user, without having to go through my application again.

So far, I have been able to get the authentication cookie just fine, but I can't figure out a way to send it to client. I was hoping i could just add it to the current `HttpResponse` and send it to the client that way,

but it uses `HttpCookies`, not `.Net.Cookies`, which is what the `HttpWebResponse` object returns from my "behind-the-scenes" post. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach to send the response cookie back with the next request is fine to retain the login state, but unfortunately in .NET there isn't any built in conversion between the two very similar but different types. You can do the following though:

```
foreach(Cookie cookie in response.Cookies)
{
    request.Cookies.Add(new System.Web.HttpCookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value) { Domain = cookie.Domain, Expires = cookie.Expires });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain this is not possible as the cookie you send the client will only be "owned" by your site and thus different than the one you received.  You may want to look at implementing single sign on or federated authentication depending on your needs.